# How to increment simple counter and counter with object component using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

(Plese help to fix my code)I want to write counter increment code in order to understand redux with situation :

1. able to increase simple counter
2. able to increase counter with object
3. now, facing the counter1 undefied in the main page

This is my reducer and how I created

```
import * as ActionTypes from "../ActionTypes";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  counter: {
    counter1: 0,
    counter2: 0,
    counter3: {
      innerCount1: 0,
      innerCount2: 0,
    },
  },
};

export const Auth = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  let a;
  switch (type) {
    case ActionTypes.INCREMENT1:
      a = {
        ...state,
        counter: {
          counter1: counter1 + 1,
        },
      };
      return a;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Auth;
```

ActionTypes file

```
export const INCREMENT1 = "INCREMENT1";
```

And main page

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { incrementCounter1 } from "./states/redux/ActionCreators/auth";
import { connect, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const CounterReduxScreen = ({ counterRedux, incrementCounter1 }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleCounterIncrement1 = async () => {
    incrementCounter1();
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Redux Pratice</Text>

      <Button title="Increase" onPress={handleCounterIncrement1} />
      <View>
        <Text>Value first counter: {counterRedux.counter1}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    counterRedux: state.counter,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    incrementCounter1: () => dispatch(incrementCounter1()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CounterReduxScreen);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting up the state incorrectly inside your reducer for the `case ActionTypes.INCREMENT1`. Make the below change to fix it:

```
case ActionTypes.INCREMENT1:
  a = {
    ...state,
    counter: {
      // ...state.counter is needed so that counter2 and counter3 values are not removed
      ...state.counter,
      // counter1 is not directly accessible which is why you're getting the error
      // you need to access it via state.counter as shown below
      counter1: state.counter.counter1 + 1,
    },
  };
  return a;
```

And for incrementing the value of `counter3`'s `innerCount1` you can update the state as shown below:

```
case ActionTypes.INCREMENT3A:
  a = {
    ...state,
    counter: {
      ...state.counter,
      counter3: {
        ...state.counter.counter3,
        innerCount1: state.counter.counter3.innerCount1 + 1,
      },
    },
  };
  return a;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. How about for counter3.innerCount1?
I declared as below, and it not works...
  a = {
    ...state,
    counter: {
   ...state.counter.counter3,
   innerCount1: state.counter.counter3..innerCount + 1,
    },
  };
  return a;

Comment: Do you want to handle this in the same action type or a separate action type ?

Comment: I handle it with separate action type. Like case ActionTypes.INCREMENT3A

Comment: Updated my answer to handle `ActionTypes.INCREMENT3A`.